# Update a column in a data frame with the index of another column in another data frame in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames in pandas python:

df1:

```
     Fruit   Origin  
0    Apple   Spain
1    Apple   France
2    Apple   Italy
3    Banana  Germany
4    Banana  Portugal
5    Grapes  France
6    Grapes  Spain
```

df2:

```
     Fruit
0    Apple
1    Banana
2    Grapes
```

and I want to modify the column Fruit in the df1 by the index of each fruit in df2, the result I am looking for should look like:

df1:

```
     Fruit   Origin  
0    0       Spain
1    0       France
2    0       Italy
3    1       Germany
4    1       Portugal
5    2       France
6    2       Spain
```

What I tried that works is:

```
df1['Fruit'] = df1.Fruit.apply(lambda x: df2.index[df2.Fruit == x])
```

However I am working with a big data set so it takes too much time, I am looking for a faster option to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using `join`. First we'll want to set the index of `df2` to be the `Fruits` column:

```
df2 = df2.reset_index().set_index('Fruit')
```

So that

```
        index
Fruit        
Apple       0
Banana      1
Grapes      2
```

Now we just write:

```
>>> df1.join(df2, on='Fruit')

    Fruit    Origin  index
0   Apple     Spain      0
1   Apple    France      0
2   Apple     Italy      0
3  Banana   Germany      1
4  Banana  Portugal      1
5  Grapes    France      2
6  Grapes     Spain      2
```